# Authenticating Angular API Call to Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.1

I am building an application using Laravel and Angular. I have defined the following route

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
Route::resource('getdealsbymerchant/{merchant_id}', 'dealsController@getdealsbymerchant',
    array('only' => array('index')));
});
```

I have this route working. When I hit it I get a JSON response.

I have also been able to make API call in Angular to read the data and displayed it.

In my app.js I have defined

```
var app = angular.module('deals', [])
    .constant('API_URL', 'http://www.coupon.local/api/getdealsbymerchant/');
```

I am aware that I can protect routes by adding

```
'middleware' => 'auth',
```

to the route.

My question is how do I authenticate my Angular application to make sure that only the angular application has access to the API and not everyone else.

Do I pass username and password in the app.js or is there a better way of doing it? Also since app.js is in public folder, wouldn't everyone be able to see the username password I am passing?

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: *My question is how do I authenticate my Angular application to make sure that only the angular application has access to the API and not everyone else.* - use some token? domain lock? btw, even several api provider that uses a *key* to authenticate their client but the client actually exposes the api key, just like google api browser key, twitter api key, etc.

Comment: So does this mean that if my API allows update/delete, any user can see my key and use it to access API and update/delete records? Sorry I am not able to wrap my head around this authentication so asking.

Comment: actually, you could instead of *authenticating* your application - you could do this per-user basis. like explained in [scotch.io token based authentication for angular js and laravel app](https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps), you could authenticate user instead - it's more secure and we only need a *session* key - that being generated on user login and discarded later (by inactivity or logout). **ps** and yes, *it mean that if my API allows update/delete, any user can see my key and use it to access API* if you use application key.

Comment: I use this tip: At logon, I send with https the username (plain) and password (sha-256) to server. The server returns an API key (stored on account data, something like current time millis with sha-256, generated for each password change), and I use some Angular Local Storage to store the basic auth information (Basic <apikey>=<password>). And then, I use a global resource configuration to send this for each call.

Answer (score 1):

Storing any user or password , keys etc.. in angular is a bad idea because it makes it visible for the user.. The best way I know is to make a middle layer ... so instead of calling this endpoint : 
http://www.coupon.local/api/getdealsbymerchant/

angular should call : 
http://www.coupon.local/getdealsbymerchant 
which internally will do the call to the api and has all the private things in server side

Comment: I am not sure I am following. Should I have a PHP file for this call   http://www.coupon.local/getdealsbymerchant. If that's the case wouldn't everyone else be able to get to that path too? How does it differentiate between AngularJS application call vs. a regular user call?

Comment: You can create a controller in your laravel app that will just call your api. What you gain from this is that the call that goes to laravel is already authenticated, so no one else can call it unless authenticated